# Is there an easy solution to my collision issue?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm trying to make a simple sliding puzzle game in unity and have put together some code that works for moving the blocks. One parameter that's a must is, once the block has stared moving I'd like it to no longer accept input until it has come to a stop. I've got this too work however if the block is in contact with a wall and I press for the block to go towards that wall again, the isStopped bool is set permanently to false and the block can't be moved again (you can see this in the bottom right of the gif). Am I doing something stupid? Is there an easy way to circumvent this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Moving : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float speed = 100;
    public bool isStopped = true;
  
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && isStopped)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * speed );
            isStopped = false;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && isStopped)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.down * speed );
            isStopped = false;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && isStopped)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.left * speed );
            isStopped = false;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && isStopped)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * speed );
            isStopped = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        isStopped = true;
    }

    /* private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision) 
    {
        isStopped = true;
    } */
}
```

[image: Gif of issue]

Comment: I suggest recording the last direction that was moved as well. The last movement can't be repeated even while `isStopped` is active. I'm not sure if `OnCollisionEnter2D` would be able to capture that though (you can give it a shot) but I'm sure it's doable in one way or another.

Comment: This would mean adding a property that stores the direction, perhaps suggesting a nullable `enum` for this. When the game starts it's null. in every branch for pressing the key down you store the updated direction in this new field member. For each key down logic you need to add a condition to each if to ensure the direction stored in the property is `.hasValue` and `.Value` is not representing the same direction.

Comment: Oh actually there is a flaw with this one, if I go left, then down. This would prevent me from going down but not left. But I got a workaround for that.

Answer (score 1):

Example:
Make an enum class (or see if an existing one exists) representing direction.

```
namespace Blah.Blah.Blah;

public enum Direction
{
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right,
}
```

Then we need a property which tracks the available movement directions. In this case it's easier because we have a rectangular area. We use this set to verify that the direction movement is available for each condition.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Moving : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float speed = 100;
    public bool isStopped = true;
    public HashSet<Direction> availableMovements = new HashSet<Direction>();
  
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        // Need to initialize available movements (Assuming we start without touching any wall)
        availableMovements.Add(Direction.Up);
        availableMovements.Add(Direction.Down);
        availableMovements.Add(Direction.Left);
        availableMovements.Add(Direction.Right);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && isStopped && availableMovements.Contains(Direction.Up))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * speed );
            isStopped = false;
            availableMovements.Remove(Direction.Up);
            availableMovements.Add(Direction.Down);
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && isStopped && availableMovements.Contains(Direction.Down))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.down * speed );
            isStopped = false;
            availableMovements.Remove(Direction.Down);
            availableMovements.Add(Direction.Up);
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && isStopped && availableMovements.Contains(Direction.Left))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.left * speed );
            isStopped = false;
            availableMovements.Remove(Direction.Left);
            availableMovements.Add(Direction.Right);
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && isStopped && availableMovements.Contains(Direction.Right))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * speed );
            isStopped = false;
            availableMovements.Remove(Direction.Right);
            availableMovements.Add(Direction.Left);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        isStopped = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all Omar I just want to say thank you for all your effort. I'm going to go and brush up on enumerators and also another suggestion that someone made which is to scrap rigidbody physics all together and go down the route of making a 2D array and tracking the position of the block. Hopefully my answer lies in one of these two directions.

Comment: I just want to say your method was brilliant and worked perfectly first time. However the moment I have a slightly more complex map such as a narrow passage that leads to a dead-end, it brings back in the same issue. So I'm going to start again from scratch I think and see what other methods may take me further. 
Thank you again though for your time and effort, it's really appreciated.

Comment: Yes I agree, The same framework I have above can be used however what would need to change is how we determine which moves are available. Once the maps get more complicated I can imagine other options might require doing some math between colliders (which might not be efficient if you are tracking more than one) or something with physics. Nothing comes immediately to mind other than physics raycasting but that would require further investigation.

Comment: Indeed it appears [physics raycasting](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) could work here. I have only used the regular raycast but a hurdle you might come across is hiding the collider of the object you are moving. I believe the layer mask would help there. In this case you might not at all need the hashset check. However I suspect that it will fire for each frame if you do use it (which is not good). Using physics raycast in `Update` is probably gonna be a bad idea (would make sense in `FixedUpdate` since it's tied to physics engine).

Comment: So perhaps every time the box collides with a wall you might want to run a physics raycast in all 4 directions and regenerate `availableMovements`. I would do this before setting `isStopped = true;`

Comment: It would be more work for me to go and implement that but if you have any questions I would be happy to give some tips.

Comment: I just want to say firstly, you're extremely kind for dedicating so much attention to this problem, I genuinely had no idea that this "simple first project" of mine would bring up so many complications and fear my little fun project might be far to beyond my current scope - I've only been learning for 2/3 months.
I was looking at this video and thinking about how I could implement something similar, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3iEl5AwUF8.
But I'm also thinking that maybe I should continue learning C# and Unity before trying to take my project any further.

Comment: Any more help and I feel I should be paying you for private lessons, hahaha.

Comment: I personally feel working with console apps and doing school-like problems is the best way to start. Once you are good with any language you can jump to this kind of stuff.

Comment: Yeah it's clear I'm going to have to drill C# over and over until I'm much more comfortable with it before I can jump into Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a small thing. Try this to see if it lets you continue motion if you run into a wall:

```
 //create a way to disable input
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public static bool IsInputEnabled = true;
 }
```

Preventing motion is a second issue if this first part works we solve it one way and if not, another.

I'd recommend changing your if statements to a case block also for what you are doing here. Since you should only ever move cardinal directions and there isn't a need to know if someone is moving left AND up, case would work.

Comment: Hey Rodger, thank you for your help. This is my first project so I'm sorry if my questions come across as dense. I've already managed to stop the block from receiving an input until it comes to a stop with my isStopped bool. The issue arises when I try and move the block towards a wall it's already in contact with.

Comment: Also, I've never seen movement done with a switch statement before, can you have switch statements with 2 arguments?